# WPF sending rapid commands to external hardware

Tags: c#, wpf, hardware, external, mousemove

I have a servo controller connected to my laptop, to control it i created a WPF application, i created a slider control that when value changed would send the position to the servo.

That worked as a charm, and the servo is moving very smooth.
Then i added a image and attached a mouse move event, so that when i moved my mouse over the image, it would move the servo to where the mouse is pointed at on the image.

But when i do that, it seems that the wpf application isn't sending as many commands as when i used the slider control.
The servo controller i pretty quick, and the slider worked really well, but the image mouseover makes the servo move really bumpy.

What could i do to make it faster?
I just need to fire ALOT of commands at certain times, like when the mouse is over the image, or when the application is running in another mode where it sends commands automaticly.
The more commands the servo controller is reciving, the smoother the servo is moving.

Could i use another thread to send the commands or something?

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: I think the problem is the opposite, you are sending *too many* commands when you use the mouse.  Forcing the servo to constant acc/decel.  Display the servo commands and compare.

Comment: I'l test that when i get back, should be pretty easy to do with a for loop and some thread.sleeps =)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending to many commands the [Reactive Extensions for .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896) might be interesting. They allow you to create Linq queries on an event source and throttle the events.